# Deploy To multiple production servers

Tags: docker, github, gitlab, autodeploy

We have a main repository based on Gitlab CD/CI. 
Now with our grows, we had a hard time to update each of our customer's apps using auto deploy with Git.

Now we're looking for a solution when production stage success and tests passed then all of our customers get the latest deployment and pull updates automatically. (Continues Delivery)

There is a [deploy to production](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/index.html) in Gitlab but it goes for single production we want to duplicate this steps for each mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab-CI deploy stage can have multiple environments, which you can set each to automatic/manual deployment.

Example: just change the staging to customer1, production to customer2 and add as many as you need.

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script: echo "Running tests"

build:
  stage: build
  script: echo "Building the app"

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to staging server"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.example.com
  only:
  - master

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to production server"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://example.com
  when: manual
  only:
  - master
```

Another solution would be in application automatic updates if you dont have access to your customers environments.

Also checkout **Spinnaker** which seems to be designed for CD specifically.

Comment: let's imagine you have 500 customers are we going to add new customers URL to script? I don't think so

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out [DeployHQ](https://www.deployhq.com). It supports deploying to unlimited servers at the same time.

Comment: it's a great tool but we looking for an in-house solution.